# Install Campaign measurement data not recorded

Tags: ios, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

I want to track the install campaign's for iOS app. I have integrated google analytics SDK. And followed the steps mentioned in google doc.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns

And I created campaign URL using URL builder tool provided by google.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#url-builder

And I have given following data while building URL.
Google Analytics Property ID : UA-xxxxxx-1
Add network : custom
Redirect URL : store url
App ID : com.xxxxxxx.xxxxx
Campaign Source : google
.
.
Campaign Name : Test campaign

And generated url I pasted into My google plus page.
And from the device I clicked the link, It redirected to iStore and I installed the app.

So when I checked google dashboard. There I didn't find any campaign data.
Can anybody help me to find what may the problem?